# Read an ini file in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ini

I'm trying to read a simple .ini file in Haskell to use as configuration for my application. I'm not an expert in Haskell so I may be missing something simple.

So far my simplified code looks like this

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}

import Data.Ini

main :: IO ()
main = do
  config <- readIniFile "config.ini"
  p <- lookupValue "NETWORK" "port" config

  ...
```

The compiler gives me this error

Couldn't match expected type 'Ini' with actual type 'Either String Ini' in the third argument of lookupValue namely 'config'.

I looked at the [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ini-0.3.5/docs/Data-Ini.html#t:Ini) for Data.Ini but I cannot find any example of how to use the Api.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like config returns an Either String Ini rather than just an Ini. Just pattern match on the config, `case config of Left err -> putStrLn err; Right c -> do lookupValue ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation, `readIniFile` returns an `IO (Either String Ini)`, but the third argument of `lookupValue` must be an `Ini` (and it returns an `Either String Text`). You need to use a case statement to retrieve the ini:

```
result <- readIniFile "config.ini"
p <- case result of
         Left str -> Left str
         Right ini -> lookupValue "NETWORK" "port" ini
```

Reading the source code, the Left discriminant seems to be used for reporting error messages.

If you want to get fancier, you can use Either as a monad: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Either.html#t:Either

```
result <- readIniFile "config.ini"
p <- (result >>= (lookupValue "Network" "port"))
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `readIniFile` returns an `IO (Either String Ini)`. And `lookupValue` expects an `Ini` value. So you have to unwrap the ini value from inside the `Either` and provide proper handling of errors.

I'm pretty sure there's a more monadic and expressive way to solve the problem but here comes a solution.

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Ini

main :: IO ()
main = do
    config <- readIniFile "config.ini"
    case config of
        Right ini -> do
            let p = lookupValue "NETWORK" "port" ini
            putStrLn $ case p of
                        Left s -> s
                        Right t -> show t
        Left s -> putStrLn s
```